# Docker compose spring boot redis connection issue

Tags: docker, spring-boot, redis, docker-compose

I am running a simple rest app with `redis` running in a docker container/docker-compose. I believe, `redis` must be accessible to spring boot using `http://redis:6379`. But, it throws the error:

```
018-07-22 21:53:33.972 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

My code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/GAKAY/dockercompose/src/master/).

Comment: shouldnt you have a service definition for redis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using alias in links, you have to use the hostname identical to the alias to access the container.
Therefore you can do one of following,

use http://localhost:6379 instead of http://redis:6379 in your spring boot application

or,

change

```
links:
 - "redis:localhost"
```

to

```
links:
 - "redis"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I Was Facing this Issue for two days and final I got the answer above.
i was missing please see below my docker-cmpose.yaml
  **links:
        - "redis"**

----------------------------------------
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo:5.0.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGODB_USER
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGODB_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - $MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT:$MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
  app:
    links:
        - "redis"
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
      #- cache
    build: ./order-service
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
          "spring.data.mongodb.uri" : "mongodb://$MONGODB_USER:$MONGODB_PASSWORD@mongo_db:$MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT/$MONGODB_DATABASE?authSource=admin"
        }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:
```